# Strange performance issue with Runnable in Android

Tags: android, performance, runnable

I'm developing a 3D app in Android using OpenGL ES. To show some debug informations such as fps, I update TextViews through `runOnUIThread()`. I've tested 2 ways to do this : the first way by passing a new `Runnable`

```java
runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("some text");
    }
});
```

The second by passing a `Runnable` object, instanciated once

```java
MyRunnable runnableObject = new MyRunnable();
...
runOnUIThread(runnableObject);
```

The purpose of the second way is to avoid creating a new object each time the TextViews are updated, so it should be more efficient. However, the first way is a bit more efficient. It doesn't matter for the final app, but I'd like to understand why the first is more efficient.

Comment: How did you measure efficiency?

Comment: It is not a real measure, but fps drops down with the second way.

Comment: Well, the second one is more memory consuming because you are storing a variable of custom type. First time is just anonymous field with inline initialization... I guess.

Comment: Then that's very weird. It's hard to believe that a field access is slower than calling a constructor (not to mention all the garbage collection). This is grasping at straws, but is `runnableObject` perhaps a private field and is the call to `runOnUIThread` being made from code in an inner class? That would have to go through a compiler-generated access method, which would slow it down a bit (but not, enough, I think, to explain what you're reporting).

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski - The first one is also creating an object of custom type. It just happens to be an anonymous type. Storing the value once in a variable and reusing it should be _faster_ (not slower!) than regenerating it every time.

Comment: I'm no expert in java, but maybe the compiler is doing some optimization that makes the first case faster than the second one.

Comment: Or maybe, the second case is slower, because each next time `MyRunnable` is called, it waits for the previous one to finish - since it's the same instance.

Comment: That make sense! I'm gonna do some tests.